# How can I selectively change text using a CSS class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add a CSS/HTML 'fragment' to a page to change the text in the following:

```
<div> 
    <h3 class="category-heading">Keep this text:</h3>
</div>
<div> 
    <h3 class="category-heading">**Change this text**:</h3>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
<style>
    h3.category-heading {
        text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    h3.category-heading::after {
        content: “New and Featured Products”;
        text-indent: 0;
        display: block;
        line –height: 120%;
    }
</style>
```

But this changed both instances of the text.

Is it possible to specify the second instance of the css class to be changed? or is it possible to select and change the wording in the second css class by adding a html fragment?

Comment: You need to set a unique id for that h3 or if this is the last one, you can use the `:last-child` pseudo code.

Comment: given your current markup posted you would have to change the selector to: `div + div h3.category-heading::after { .. }`

Comment: Try this one too http://jsfiddle.net/cxc0d1rt/ uisng `after` on the div instead of `h3`

Comment: @Danko you change the html, and the OP can't. Can you use javascript ?

Comment: Probably? But not too sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you can use Javascript by including it an HTML fragment :

Depending on the inclusion mecanism (we need to know more about the tools you use), something containing :

```
<script>
     window.onload = function(){
          document.getElementsByClassName("category-heading")[1].innerHTML = "New and Featured Products";
     }
</script>
```

If the first solution breaks some features of your website (because It could override defined behaviour), you should use :

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("category-heading")[1].innerHTML = "New and Featured Products";
</script>
```

Comment: Does the [1] indicate which of the class: category-heading to select, I.e replacing with [2] would select the second category -heading div?

Comment: This code does not seem to work?
    <script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("category-heading")[1].innerHTML = "New and Featured Products";
    </script>

However this one does but with a delay. 
    <script>
     window.onload = function(){
          document.getElementsByClassName("category-heading")[1].innerHTML = "New and Featured Products";
     }
    </script>

Why would one work and not the other?

Comment: Depending on how your tool loads the differents fragments, you may need to wait or not that everything is load before selecting your category-heading. But if window.onload is overriden by the tool, the first solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use an id attribute?

```
<h3 class="category-heading" id="itemThatShouldBeChanged">**Change this text**:</h3>
```

and than just
    #itemThatShouldBeChanged {content:"other text"}

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the code, only add html/CSS fragments to the page.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)
Be aware that this is CSS3

this will give you the following css selector :

```
 div:nth-child(2) h3.category-heading::after
```

Comment: That still wont work! You would need to do `div:nth-child(2) h3.category-heading::after `

Comment: Would this specify the second instance (div) of h3.category-heading ? Or the second div in the code? (Example above is extracted from several lines of code/div etc.

Comment: Ok, so I would have to specify nth-child(50) for example to specify the specific div?

Comment: In such a case, CSS selector (particularly nth-child), does not really suit your needs, as a change in your HTML will ask you to change the CSS (to 51 ...).

Comment: Ok, so is possible as long as I don't change the HTML before it.  Is it possible to use: var str and var res coding to replace the text only? I'm not sure what the coding would be for this.